Verify cell identity
We want to analyze from an article the sequencing data (3 rd generation) of the U2OS line, and we would like to verify if it is that cell line. I was wondering how would be the general procedure, or if there is any tutorial for it.
I was thinking about performing a STR profiling with ExpansionHunter or Tandem Repeats Finder, for example of CSF1PO or D13S317. I was also wondering if I would need to perform a Variant call with GATK before.
